# Allure report is NaN% via allure-maven plugin

Tags: java, maven, junit, allure

I trying view Allure report generated by maven-plugin and JUnit 5 but html page is empty

I build my reports via `mvn clean test` then I use `mvn allure:serve` and it builds without error. But opened allure site is empty or contains NaN values.

Starting allure site with `allure serve target/surefire-reports` generates proper web page

Build log contains no errors and says that all fine, after generating i found on `/allure-results` many json files with reports, containing information with project tests and containers:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ----------------------< org.example:TestProject >-----------------------
[INFO] Building TestProject 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- allure-maven:2.10.0:serve (default-cli) @ TestProject ---
[WARNING] The artifact xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:2.0.2 has been relocated to xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.0.b2
[INFO] Allure installation directory C:\Users\Я\IdeaProjects\TestProject/.allure
[INFO] Try to finding out allure 2.8.1
[INFO] Generate Allure report (serve) with version 2.8.1
[INFO] Generate Allure report to C:\Users\Я\IdeaProjects\TestProject\target\site/allure-maven-plugin
[INFO] Found results directory C:\Users\Я\IdeaProjects\TestProject\allure-results
[INFO] Can't find information about categories.
[INFO] Generate report to C:\Users\Я\IdeaProjects\TestProject\target\site\allure-maven-plugin
Generating report to temp directory...
Report successfully generated to C:\Users\4483~1\AppData\Local\Temp\8774552783003673881\allure-report
Starting web server...
2021-12-22 22:16:25.525:INFO::main: Logging initialized @1032ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.StdErrLog
Server started at <http://192.168.56.1:64312/>. Press <Ctrl+C> to exit
```

My pom.xml:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>org.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>TestProject</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>TestProject</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <aspectj.version>1.8.10</aspectj.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
      <artifactId>allure-junit5</artifactId>
      <version>2.17.2</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
      <version>5.8.2</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
      <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
      <version>4.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
      <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
      <version>5.0.3</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.21.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <testFailureIgnore>false</testFailureIgnore>
          <argLine>
            -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar"
          </argLine>
          <systemProperties>
            <property>
              <name>junit.jupiter.extensions.autodetection.enabled</name>
              <value>true</value>
            </property>
          </systemProperties>
        </configuration>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0</version>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
          <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
          <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
          <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
        <artifactId>allure-maven</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.0</version>
        <configuration>
<!--          <reportVersion>2.4.1</reportVersion>-->
          <buildDirectory>${project.basedir}</buildDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

[screenshot of site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VVsY2.png)

Answer (score 0):

I faced with the same situation. pls try to change the `allure-junit5.version` to `2.16.1`, in my case it was the last properly working one.
each one above it behaves similarly with NaN% in report

---

UPDATE: you can use a version above `2.16.1`, but configure the `allure-maven` plugin with `reportVersion` tag, e.g. for version `2.17.2`:

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
   <artifactId>allure-maven</artifactId>
   <version>2.11.2</version>
   <configuration>
       <reportVersion>2.17.2</reportVersion>
       <resultsDirectory>${project.build.directory}/allure-results</resultsDirectory>
       <reportDirectory>${project.build.directory}/allure-report</reportDirectory>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems have spaces in one of the parent folder name under which allure-results exist. So, if there are space in folder name, keep the folder name in double quates and then run allure serve command as:

Incorrect: allure serve D:\test automation\webautomation\allure-results

Correct: allure serve D:"test automation"\webautomation\allure-results